# HttpURLConnection throws java.io.IOException: insufficient data written

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I developed a dispatcher application and when I do tests I get the exception IOException: insufficient data written this is the part of code that's throws the error:

```
final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(getUrl()).openConnection();
final int timeout =200;
final HttpRequestContext data = getData();//data contains the data send in the request to dispatche
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
for (final Entry<String, List<String>> entry : data.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
    for (final String value : entry.getValue()) {
    connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), value);
    }
}
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
if (data.getContentLength() > 0) {
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getContentLength());
}
connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
connection.setRequestMethod(data.getMethod());
final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    final HttpRequestContext data = getData();

if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(data.getBody())) {
    LOGGER.debug("No data to send");
} else {
    IOUtils.write(data.getBody(), connection.getOutputStream());
}
}
```

Log:

```
java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3501)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1470)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at com.dhl.dispatcher.HttpRequestWriter.doRun(HttpRequestWriter.java:78)
at com.dhl.dispatcher.AbstractRequestWriter.run(AbstractRequestWriter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: post the full log please!

Comment: Why are you setting the content-length to the length of the request body? And why are you setting it but not sending anything back?

Comment: i updated the answer

Comment: It could be masking something else, since it's "at close time" (ex: connection was aborted by server for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never send any data but you set

```
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getContentLength());
```

you need to do smth like this before u get the response:

```
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(body);
        out.close();
```

---

UPDATE:
doing

> final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

makes the request

you have to add the body before that.

Comment: Thanks you. I resolve the problem by setting the body before connection.getResponseCode();

Comment: welcome! btw if you are just starting to write your android client I suggest you to try https://github.com/apptik/jus its based on volley but quite more evolved and easier :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be deleted if it's not being used:

```
if (data.getContentLength() > 0) {
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getContentLength());
}
```

This is the part of the code that's causing the `insufficient data written` exception.